# I want to remove Controller and function name from URL in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

My current URL is
 http://myaliveidea.com/news/news/readmore/78/Hacker-drama-Mr.-Robot-is-granted-full-series-by-USA-Network

http://myaliveidea.com/news/ -> This is base url.

news -> is controller name

readmore -> is function name

78/Hacker-drama-Mr.-Robot-is-granted-full-series-by-USA-Network -> my blog id and his title

so i want to remove controller and  function name from url 
 like this

http://myaliveidea.com/news/78/Hacker-drama-Mr.-Robot-is-granted-full-series-by-USA-Network

Comment: Use Routing : https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html

Comment: @Hirdesh check this url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7094302/codeigniter-is-it-possible-to-remove-the-controller-function-from-the-url-usi?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

If you would like the news controller to be your main controller. You will have to set it up in your routes so when you go to http://myaliveidea.com it will go to the news controller, with out showing controller name. I would remove the `/news/` from your base url and set news as default controller in routes.

```
$route['default_controller'] = "news"; gets index from controller

$route['default_controller'] = "news/readmore";
```

Also good CI tutorials on here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9hRNFgSLLAQ

Answer (score 0):

Check documentation for routing in Code igniter user guide.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a _remap() function in your controller. This way, if you have dynamic data, you don't have worry about updating your routes.php

https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/controllers.html#remapping

Put the following code(not fully tested) inside your News controller.

```
/**
 * Intercept all calls to this class. 
 * 
 * @access private
 * @param string
 * @param array
 * @return boolean
 */
function _remap($method, $params)
{
    // If method exists, call that method.
    if (method_exists($this, $method) !== false) return call_user_func_array(array($this, $method), $params);

    // Method is actually a news_id and 1st parameter is title
    $sql = 'SELECT news_id FROM news WHERE news_id = ? AND title = ?';
    $news_id = $method;
    $title = (isset($params[0])) ? $params[0] : '';
    $qobj = $this->db->query($sql, array($method, $title); 

    if ($qobj->num_rows()) {
        return $this->readmore($news_id, $title);
    }

    // Non-existing method
    show_404();
}
```