# I want to remove controller as well as function name from url

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller

I need help to rewrite url and remove controller as well as function name from url given url is my current uel.

URL :http://localhost/example/Loadercontrol/detail/200

I want this type of url

URL : http://localhost/example/name  (replace id with name).

I already try rewrite url as well as

```
$route['example'] = 'localhost/example/Loadercontrol/detail';
```

but it's not working. I've really tried to fix the issue. Please help me.

Comment: Hey, I think you need to use ```slug``` for this. But as you don't want the controller name also, then you need to create the routes from database somehow in ```routes.php```

Comment: if you don't want to write the routes from database then you can do this.
```$routes["(:any)"] = "Loadercontrol/(:any');```. But it will harm to your 404 page redirection.

Comment: search the slug like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305786/using-slugs-in-codeigniter hope it will help you.

Comment: This link will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7094302/codeigniter-is-it-possible-to-remove-the-controller-function-from-the-url-usi?rq=1

Comment: still i fetch same issue i alredy try in routes.php and   $route['example/(:num)'] = 'example/Loadercontrol/detail/$1';

Comment: i already try  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7094302/codeigniter-is-it-possible-to-remove-the-controller-function-from-the-url-usi?rq=1 this linkk but i can't fix issue

Comment: just do as Hikmat suggested below, but replace :num by :any

Answer (score 1):

Try like this..

```
$route['example/(:num)'] = 'example/Loadercontrol/detail/$1';
```

For details see more here...https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html#wildcards

Wildcards are actually aliases for regular expressions, with `:any` being translated to [^/]+ and `:num` to [0-9]+, respectively.

Comment: I think he need to replace :num by :any (in his example he wanted to use **name**)